# auto-accept SSL certificates in Windows

Tags: ssh, certificate

we use some software that will ssh to a bunch of machines and do something.  The problem is in our test lab, the vm's are re-new (destroy and re-created) very often, so the software will treat the vm as new, which it is, and will fail because the authenticity of the host cannot be established.  I ended up manually putty in, accept the cert., and the software will be happy.  Putty in a few hundreds vm's is not fun :-(

So, I want to know is there any Windows command tool that I can automate to accept the certificate?  (We are in a closed lab, so I am not too worry about security)

Thanks in advance!

PS: I know there are some solutions for Linux env., but this one is Windows

Comment: You can use `cygwin` and standard `openssh` from their repository with all the pros and cons of linux environment.

Comment: Thanks. That idea came across my mind, but I was hoping for a simpler tool.  It's a start.  I need to dig a little deeper to see if it will work.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the answer from another post to use pscp.exe `C:\> echo y | pscp.exe -l user -pw password -ls 192.168.0.1:/`, and can be scripted to loop through multiple IP's, etc

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using the standard distribution of PuTTY, there are no arguments you can give it that will auto-accept host unknown host keys. The developer is simply against the idea in principal due to security concerns. Read it from the horse's mouth [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/accept-host-keys.html).

However, you can work around the problem outside of PuTTY if you know all of the host keys in advance.  PuTTY is just checking a registry location in HKCU for known hosts.  So you can basically just pre-populate HKCU with your known hosts before running PuTTY.  There are a variety of ways you can do that.  The page referenced above even has a link to a script that will convert a 'known_hosts' file to a .REG file.